# Update constraints of other elements when UITableView height change

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` of which I am defining height as 200 in autolayout. Based on that I am laying out other elements below it like `UITextField` etc. After that in run time I am fetching data from server and populating in `UITableView` due to which i am updating `UITableView`'s height based on its content size. Following code I am using for it

```
self.myTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0 , 0, self.myTableView.frame.width, self.myTableView.contentSize.height)
```

But due to this, all the elements placed below `UITableView` still appear at same location which they were while laying out in Autolayout. Means change in height of `UITableView` makes no difference to them. Following image depicts this problem. What could be possible solution for this?

[image]

Here you can see, text fields are getting overlapped on tableview at run time. I am using Swift 2 in Xcode 7.2

Comment: Do you update the constraints after receiving data when table view's size changes?

Comment: Yes I change height of `UITableView` after receiving and reloading data

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have all required constraints to your table view and other view.

Don't change the frame of TableView to change height of it.
Instead create IBOutlet of height constraint of your tablview.

e.g. say IBOutlet name is constraintTableViewHeight,
then you can the the hight easily.

```
constraintTableViewHeight.constant = yourNewHeightValue
//update all constraint of your view and its inner view
self.view.layoutIfNeeded();
```

Refer Image to create IBOutlet for your height Constraint.

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my limited knowledge but how can I create IBOutlet of height constraint?

Comment: Have you created IBOutlet of button or label before ?

Comment: You are welcom.! @Abhi

Answer (score 1):

Take IBOutlet of `NSLayoutConstraint` for tableView Height  and set its value not set tableview frame it's not working if you are already given constraints for tableview so change tableview hight constant

like if you take tblHeight for tableView height then set `tblHeight.constant = self.myTableView.contentSize.height`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an outlet connection for your table view height constraint:

```
@IBOutlet var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and when you want to change table view height, you can change the constraint value like this:

```
heightConstraint.constant = newHeightValue
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```