# Swift : Change size of UIButton programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, storyboard

I have a UIButton in storyboard and i am trying to change its frame programmatically but its not working, nothing is changing. Ive tried this:

```
        button.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)
```

Any idea why this isn't working and how i can get it to work?

Comment: `button.frame`! Not `button.layer.frame`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However it didn't seem to work. @NSNoob

Comment: You must be using autolayout then. Is that right? also where are you changing the frame? You have to make sure that you do that after views have been laid out

Comment: if you are using autolayout, frame change will not work, check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759302/update-constraints-of-other-elements-when-uitableview-height-change/34759422#34759422

Comment: @HitendraHckr thats the thing, i don't think I'm using auto layout, Ive simply dragged the UIButtons onto the storyboard. How to do i turn it off so i can set the frame, or programmatically auto layout without getting conflicts?

Comment: @HitendraHckr I checked out the link, however Im building a calculator style application, and what I'm trying to achieve is that same calculator format with the UIButtons